# Percentage donuts

Tags: graphics

How do i get to make such figures in latex?[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 1):

An answer with simple tikz commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgf}


\newcommand*{\makedonut}[4][1]{%
 \pgfmathsetmacro\pertoarc{#3*3.6}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]%
    \node at (0,0.5) {#3 \%};%
    \node at (0,-.5) {#4};%
    \draw[#2,line width=0.5cm] (0,3) arc (90:{90-\pertoarc}:3cm) coordinate (B);%
    \draw[#2!20!gray,line width=0.5cm] (B) arc ({90-\pertoarc}:-270:3cm);%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent text before the donut:

\makedonut{cyan}{64}{\Large text here}

another one :

\makedonut[0.4]{red}{89}{something}

a final:

\makedonut[0.6]{green!40!blue}{32}{nothing}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]